# Pipeline after sourcing a bashscript

Tags: bash, shell, script, pipe, gnu

I have a code

```
# Inside Child.sh
ChildVariable=BigChild

# Inside Parent.sh
source ./Child.sh 
echo "ChildVariable=${ChildVariable}"
```

Output:

```
ChildVariable=BigChild
```

---

But,

```
# Inside Parent.sh
source ./Child.sh  | sed 's/\(.*\)/\t\1/'
echo "ChildVariable=${ChildVariable}"
```

Output:

```
ChildVariable=
```

---

I need to indent the output (if any) of the `Child.sh` so, I need to pass the output to sed. But, I don't understand why the `ChildVariable` is not set?

Answer (score 2):

From [`man 1 bash`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> Each command in a pipeline is executed as a separate process (i.e., in a subshell).

You're sourcing from a subshell; the variable is set in the subshell, not in the shell running `Parent.sh`.

This will source `Child.sh` in the right shell:

```
# Inside Parent.sh
source ./Child.sh > >(sed 's/\(.*\)/\t\1/')
echo "ChildVariable=${ChildVariable}"
```

although now the output of `sed` may appear *after* the output of `echo` (a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition)). For now I think the best way to cope with the issue is to redesign the whole program, so you don't need to filter output from any sourced script.

You tagged [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) so `source` and process substitution (`> >(…)`) are OK. To make this portable(-ish?) one needs to [use `.` instead of `source`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11588636) and [introduce some tricks with fifos](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/309594/108618).

Comment: Thanks! Could you please suggest how to redesign this program, my intent is that the output of Child script be indented by a tab character?

Comment: Also, in the following `cmd 1; cmd 2 | cnd 3 | cmd 4` are all these commands  executing in different process? I thought that at least cmd 1 and cmd 2 will occur in the same shell.

Comment: @Nikhil It depends on what it does. Can you split it into two parts? I mean one part that sets variables (sourced) and one that generates the output (not sourced).

Comment: @Nikhil `cmd 1` will be run by the current shell, `cmd 2` in a subshell. Take `;` and replace it with a newline character – the result will become more obvious.

Comment: `a="A" 
echo $a
A` and
`a="A"; echo $a
A
`

Here we can see that `a="A"` and `echo $a` are run in the same shell irrespective of the semicolon or new line. Here command seperated by space are executed in newline.

Comment: @Nikhil This `echo` is not in a pipe, this makes it different from `cmd 2`. But even if it was in a pipe (thus running in a subshell) it would print the value of the variable.